# How to cache a Server Side Rendered Page using Dynamic Routes with Next.js

Tags: caching, next.js, amazon-ecs, aws-lambda-edge

I'm deploying a Next.js Application on AWS using ECS/Fargate (can't use Amplify due to custom logging and monitoring required). My Application is using api-routes and dynamic-routes with Server-Side-Rendering(getServerSideProps).

Lets say for the SSRed page the URL is something like: `domain.com/foopage/[id]?powerlevel=10000`.

The Code Looks something like:

```js
// pages/foopage/[id].tsx

import React from "react";
import type { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import Head from "next/head";

export default function FooPage({ id }: Record<string, string>) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Title</title>
      </Head>
      <main>
        <h1>
          Say Hi to <a href="https://sample-url.com/id">{id}</a>!
        </h1>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
  context.res.setHeader(
    "Cache-Control",
    "public, s-maxage=10, stale-while-revalidate=59"
  );
  const { id } = context.query;
  const response = await fetch(
    `${process.env.CMS_URL}/api/configurations?id=${id}`
  );
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();

  return {
    props: { id },
  };
};
```

I want to cache these pages so that the server doesn't have to generate the page every time.

I know that if you are using Vercel, Edge Caching works without configuration. But I'm bound to use AWS due to business-requirements. So how exactly to do it in AWS? Is it possible to do using Lambda@Edge and if so what could be the possible lambda function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that if you are using Vercel, Edge Caching works without
> configuration. But I'm bound to use AWS due to business-requirements.
> So how exactly to do it in AWS?

If you want edge caching, you need to use a CDN. Amazon's CDN is [CloudFront](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

Comment: But is it possible to do it for SRR with dynamic routes? And if yes, how? From my limited knowledge Cloudfront by default works for static assets hosted on S3.

Comment: Let's say you go to `domain.com/foopage/1?powerlevel=10000`, CloudFront will then cache the response from that request, and the next time someone goes to `domain.com/foopage/1?powerlevel=10000` that same response will be pulled from the cache instead of rendered on the server again. Is that not what you want? As long as the content of `domain.com/foopage/1?powerlevel=10000` doesn't change between users then content itself is static once it has been rendered by the server once. And no, CloudFront is not just for assets hosted on  S3, it is a CDN that works with any backend.

Comment: That should work I guess. Will deploy it on a test environment and verify. Really thanks for the help!

Comment: Also, let's say the value after `domain.com/foopage` i.e. 1,2,3 ... can have around 1000-10000 different values. is it a good idea to cache for all those different values?

Comment: It's not really hurting anything to cache all those values in the CDN. If it is beneficial or not depends on how your site traffic looks.